# Regex to find urls with hashes and exclamation marks #!

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb

Hi to all I've been looking for a regex to strip an url out of a string in javascript and I was able to get to a part of it.

the url has the following syntax

```
http://valid.url.com/#historyPage![0-9a-zA-Z_\/]+
```

separating everything

```
http:// || https://
[valid url] 
#historyPage! (this will always be the same!)
[0-9a-zA-Z_\/]+ 24 caracter mongoDB ObjectId
```

I did try using

```
/(http|ftp|https):\/\/([\w\-_]+(?:(?:\.[\w\-_]+)+))([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#!])?/i
```

But had no luck at all

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Do you just want the id at the end? Or do you actually need all the parts?

Comment: All the parts! the idea is to strip the whole url from a string!